# Is there any way to update

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have bought Solid Explorer from the playstore. I've recently bought a LYF Flame 6, which doesn't support Google Play Services, but has playstore and works just as it is supposed to. But, still I if I download Solid Explorer, it shows that only the trial version is supported. I tried manually installing a pro apk, which doesn't give updates directly from the play store. I can't download the apk each and every time a new update is released. The app doesn't show in the list of "My apps". Is there anyway to force Playstore to show Solid Explorer in the list of my apps?

Answer (score 2):

An app downloaded outside of the Play Store can't   be updated using Google Play update mechanism, it  won't appear in the downloaded list as well simply because not  your Google account that downloaded it.

An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism.

The paid version isn't showing up may be because the developer has put restrictions regarding your country or your Android version, etc.

**Update:**
Try downloading your apps from a third party market such as [Monogenie](http://m.mobogenie.com/) or [Aptoide](https://m.aptoide.com/), you'll be notified whenever an update is available.

Comment: Well, I know those apps. But as an android dev, Playstore feels better for me, in terms of both UI and features. I had asked if there was any way to make playstore to give updates for apps which I've sideloaded with the apk.

Answer (score 0):

There are also other 3rd party applications which have the ability to update installed applications, regardless from source. For instance I use an official HiApp to get updates for installed applications (even though I initially got them from Google play store).

XDA developers also made an APK updater which gets updates for installed applications. You may want to take a look here: [apk updater](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-apkupdater-t3444517). However I haven't checked if they do license verification or app purchases. If your goal is to get regular updates for your applications then it's worth a try.

Update sources:

At the moment three sources are supported:

- APKMirror
- APKPure
- Google Play (Download from Evozi)

Comment: Ok, does it support updating paid apps? How many hours do those sources take to upload the new apk from the developer? I've got this error on "Google Play (Evozi). Please review the error from this screenshot: [link](https://we.tl/fgfGhPTQCO)

Comment: @sharath3589, thanks for the update, this site uses a secure https connections and other protocols (http) are not supported. Have you tried updating within the app?

Comment: I haven't downloaded the app yet. I was trying to visit the website as I'm not on my android though. I've seen that error for many sites in my chrome, how could I fix that?

Comment: @sharath3589, aww if you having this problem on most sites, its because they can longer accept unsecure connections (http), you can try to update your chrome browser or other alteratives which don't explicitly shw this error even if the website uses http protocol